# How to change a value of an attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

in the last days i tried to change a value of a single attribute of this application File

The Xml-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd"
manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"
xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"
xmlns:xrml="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" 
xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1"
xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
 <assemblyIdentity name="lolz" version="1.1.1.1" publicKeyToken="12345" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  <description asmv2:publisher="Example" asmv2:product="Productexample2" asmv2:supportUrl="Example" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  <deployment install="true" mapFileExtensions="true" minimumRequiredVersion="1.1.1.1" trustURLParameters="true">
   <subscription>
     <update>
        <beforeApplicationStartup />
      </update>
    </subscription>
     <deploymentProvider codebase="http://Test" />
   </deployment>  
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Here i try to change the value of

`<description asmv2:product = "Productexample">`

into

`<description asmv2:product = "Productexample2">`

,and the value of

`<deploymentProvider codebase="http://Test" />`

into

`<deploymentProvider codebase="http://Test2" />`

Currently i tried :

```
private void changeAttribute (string xmlPath)
{
    string newValue = "Productexample2";
    XmlDocument xmlDoc= new XmlDocument();

    xmlDoc.Load(xmlPath);

    XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("asmv1:assembly/description/asmv2:product");
    node.Attributes[0].Value = newValue;

    xmlDoc.Save(xmlPath);
}
```

But it throws the Exception 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathException' occurred in System.Xml.dll' so i think `asmv1:assembly/description/asmv2:product` is wrong ...

any suggestions of code?

as always you can correct me in any way :)

Comment: is this a valid xml? I get `'asmv1' is an undeclared prefix`. Did you miss something like `xmlns:asmv1="..."`?

Comment: Oh sorry i deleted some namespaces :( wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a namespace manager to make the prefixes work and you need the `@` character to indicate it is an attribute you are referencing.

So this should work:

```
XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("asmv1", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1");
manager.AddNamespace("asmv2", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2");
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/asmv1:assembly/asmv1:description/@asmv2:product", manager);
```

Also, your first line in the XML root is incomplete. It should be:

```
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd"
                manifestVersion="1.0"
                xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
                xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"
                xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"
                xmlns:xrml="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3"
                xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
                xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1"
                xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2"
>
```

Comment: Still : An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathException' occurred in System.Xml.dll and it says this query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function

Comment: Okay. I fixed that using a namespace manager. See the update. The actual result is still null though. Working on it.

Comment: Node gets to null....at `XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/asmv1:assembly/description", manager);`

Comment: Fixed it. The problem was in `asmv1:description` (use the default namespace `asmv1`)

Comment: Thanks :) does work :P so i think i shall do the same at `<deploymentProvider codebase="http://Test" />`

Comment: Yes, if it has no prefix you have to use the default one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60215/discussion-between-gentle-and-patrick-hofman).